nullpointerexception inside java.xml after kryo serialization
I am writing data including some XML nodes (org.w3c.dom.Node) to a spark rdd which results in the data getting serialized and deserialized with kryo. For most nodes that works without issues and I am able to serialize and deserialize all nodes without errors. But as soon as I access .getNodeValue() of a deserialized attribute Node (java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrImpl) I get a internal nullpointer exception with the following stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.clearChunkIndex(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1991)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getLastChild(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:794)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getLastChild(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:779)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1661)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredAttrImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredAttrImpl.java:143)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrImpl.getValue(AttrImpl.java:447)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrImpl.getNodeValue(AttrImpl.java:315)

I tried accessing the node value before serialization and that works perfectly fine. But after serialization something inside the datastructure breaks. My relevant code looks like this:
public class AttributeItem implements Item {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Node attributeNode;
    private Item parent;

    public AttributeItem(Node attributeNode) {
        this.attributeNode = attributeNode;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output) {
        kryo.writeObject(output, this.parent);
        kryo.writeObject(output, this.attributeNode);
    }

    @Override
    public void read(Kryo kryo, Input input) {
        this.parent = kryo.readObject(input, Item.class);
        this.attributeNode = kryo.readObject(input, Node.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String stringValue() {
        return this.attributeNode.getNodeValue(); // BREAKS, gives nullpointer
    }


I was able to fix the problem by doing a getNodeValue() call on the node before serialization. It looks like this call has some side-effects inside the node that are needed before serialization. So if you want to serialize an xml node in java, make sure to call getNodeValue() once before serialization. Hope this can help someone else.
public class AttributeItem implements Item {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Node attributeNode;
    private Item parent;

    public AttributeItem(Node attributeNode) {
        this.attributeNode = attributeNode;
        attributeNode.getNodeValue(); // has side effects that synchronize something internal, otherwise
                                      // kryo serialization breaks
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output) {
        kryo.writeObject(output, this.parent);
        kryo.writeObject(output, this.attributeNode);
    }

    @Override
    public void read(Kryo kryo, Input input) {
        this.parent = kryo.readObject(input, Item.class);
        this.attributeNode = kryo.readObject(input, Node.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String stringValue() {
        return this.attributeNode.getNodeValue(); // now always works after serialization
    }

